# Show that the symmetry properties of a tensor are invariant

Tags: tensor-calculus

This is excerpt from Bergmann's Introduction to the Theory of Relativity. He says the proof is extremely simple, but I have no idea how to prove it.

> If a tensor is not changed when two or more indices are exchanged, then it is *symmetric* in these indices. Instances are
>    $t_{ijk} = t_{kil}, $
>   $t_{iklm} = t_{ilkm} = t_{kilm} = t_{lkim}=t_{klim}=t_{likm}.$
>   The first tensor is symmetric in its first three indices. When a tensor remains the same or changes the sign of every component upon the permutation of certain indices, the sign depending on whether it is an even or an odd permutation, we say that the tensor is *antisymmetric* with respect to these instances.
>    $t_{ijk} = -t_{kil}, $
>   $t_{iklm} = t_{ilkm} = t_{kilm}=-t_{lkim}=-t_{klim}=-t_{likm}.$
>   All such symmetric properties of a tensor are invariant. The proof is extremely simple and shall be left to the student.

Answer (score 2):

First at all we have to definie under wich transformation the tensors should be invariant. I guess you have some Lorentz transformations in mind.

Now we look at the transformation of the tensor under Lorentz transformation:

$$t_{ijk}' = \Lambda_i^a\Lambda_j^b\Lambda_k^c \ \ t_{abc} = \Lambda_i^a\Lambda_{j}^b\Lambda_{k}^c \ \ t_{bac} = \Lambda_j^b\Lambda_i^a\Lambda_k^c \ \ t_{bac} = t_{jik}'$$

Comment: These symmetry properties remain under *any* basis change.

Comment: I believe Alpha's proof outline is valid for any transformation, where $\Lambda$ generically gives any coordinate transformation.

Comment: @KeeferRowan: it is, I was just elaborating that the transformations just need to be basis tranformations (ie $\Lambda$ should be nonsingular).  The approach in the answer is indeed how you do it I think!

Comment: Okay, but I am still not sure about the antisymmetric tensor being invariant under a change of coordinates.

Comment: @MisterShine: It works in the same way. You only have to include a minus sign in step two.